# Ajax call not working with jquery ui

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

With jquery ui Sortable, when a change occurs the function 'positions' is executed. It has an ajax post in it but it doesn't get sent when positions is triggered:

```
$('#col').Sortable(
                    {
                        accept: 'widget',
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        helperclass: 'helper',
                        change:  positions,
                        handle: '.widget_title_bar'
                    }
                );
```

However, 'positions' definitely works because when I call it normally through an onclick action the ajax post gets sent. The only thing I can think of is that positions is written in javascript and not in jquery. How can I resolve this?

EDIT I have included positions below:

```
function positions(){
    var widgets = '';
    var column = document.getElementById('col');
    for(i = 0; i < col_1.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var str1 = col_1.childNodes[i].className;
        if(str1 && str1.match('widget')) widgets+='&c[1]['+i+']='+col_1.childNodes[i].id;
    }

     xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
xmlhttp.open('POST', '/positions.php', true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("widgetpositions="+widgets);
xmlhttp.send(null);


    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi Dr.Molle, I have edited in the 'positions' function into my original post above. Thanks.

Comment: What is col_1 inside the function?

Comment: Sorry, col_1 should be col. I edited some of the code to make it shorter for stackoverflow and forgot to change that.

Comment: If you are using jQuery UI you have to use jQuery and then you should probably use one of the ajax methods in jquery to make life easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript identifiers are case sensitive, there is no `.Sortable()` function is jQuery UI, use `.sortable()` instead.

```
$('#col').sortable({
    accept: 'widget',
    opacity: 0.5,
    helperclass: 'helper',
    change:  positions,
    handle: '.widget_title_bar'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the uppercase S in sortable is a typo while shortening the code, this works for me.
The error must be somewhere else, see the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/xB8Wh/
(I only have replaced "change" with "update", but it works with "change too")

The only difference a call from the change-(or any other sortable-event) will make is the scope.
So if you use somewhere the **this**-keyword inside the function, it will be #col if the function was called by a sortable-event, while calling it from a onclick-event(assigned inline) **this** will be the global window-object.

So do you use somewhere **this** inside the function?